# replace function in string containing backslash \

Tags: java, replace, backslash

I am trying to use the following code but it is giving me complilation error.
I need to replace \ \ (two backslashes) with \ (one back slash )at all occurences.

```
           if (principal.contains('\\\\') != -1)
                    {

                        {
                            principal = principal.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\");
                        }
                    }
```

Can anyone suggest something for this

Answer (score 3):

because `''` for character  , and you wrote `String` , so replace it like this:

```
   '\\\\' --->"\\\\"
```

---

and `contains` return `boolean` not `int`

```
principal.contains('\\\\')///will return true or false
```

---

and you not need for all this `{}`

```
 if (principal.contains('\\\\') != -1)
    {
        {///delete this
          principal = principal.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\");
        }////and delete this
    }
```